# Restrict nosetests coverage to only the tests that were run

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage, nose

Is there a way to have nosetests restrict the coverage information to only the tests that were run?

I know about the `cover-package` flag, but it would be nicer if you didn't have to specify the package.

This would be especially useful when running a a single unit test class that lives in a file with multiple unit test classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not know of a way in nosetests to perform this action.  I actually ended up uninstalling nosetests and using just coverage.py because it seems like nosetests and coverage don't play nicely together.  I know for a fact you can specify down to individual test methods what you want to run.  I'm not sure if that's exactly what you are looking for but I beat my head against a brick wall for days trying to get nosetests to cooperate with no luck.  Maybe it would save some effort to switch and run `coverage.py` directly instead?

Comment: I've found it works reasonably well to grep the results for the test names you're interested in